# How do I make my /data folder from RO to RW?

Tags: android

My little 1 year old nephew got a hold of my Samsung Galaxy Discovery SGH-S730G, running Android 4.0.4 - Ice Cream Sandwitch, and he messed it up to where half of my apps stops responding when I just turn it on like for example it pops up "Google Play Services has stopped." and when I try to install a new app it freezes completely. The /Data folder it on RO (Read-only) I have Android Terminal emulator and it rooted with KingRoot. I used mount -o rw,remount /data but when i use the command it says "read-only file system" it's so bad that when I uninstall an app it's back when I restart the phone.

Here's the command line output.

```
app_76@android:/ $ su

root@android:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p16 /system ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p18 /data ext4 ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc,discard 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p17 /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p19 /efs ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/sdcard fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0

root@android:/ #  mount -o rw,remount /data
mount: Read-only file system
```

Comment: I think your best bet is to do a factory reset.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/tpassets.devicebits.com/pub/66130/docs/SA%20730G%20E.pdf

Comment: Tried doing a factory reset it did nothing. I even tried volume down + power and even in safemode.

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [the guidelines for posting in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Flash TWRP recovery and and run:

```
 adb devices
```

and insure you see the devices

```
 cd /desired-directory
```

and just

```
 adb pull /sdcard
```

this should pull all the data on the device

if that doesn't work launch

```
 adb shell
```

Look for the desired folder to pull and then run the command

```
 pwd
```

copy path and run

```
adb pull $PATH
```

Might be easier to just use TWRP backup creation for the data instead, but you never know what carries on to the new device using that backup. Plus, faster to surf files just pulling them the way I mentioned above

Then just flash the device with stock using odin. MAKE SURE THE STOCK ROM is on the save rev. Example:

firmware: G900LKLU1BOD3

the number one after the letter LU should be the same that is on your device. You can check this by running the recovery before flashing TWRP. This should be at the top in RED printing